# Search Sheet 1, Cell A2 for a number contained in Sheet 2 column A and return a value from Sheet 2 Column B

Tags: excel

As the title states, I'm looking to set up a spreadsheet where I search the text in cell A2 on sheet 1, for a multiple digit number in column A in sheet 2, and return a corresponding value from Column B in sheet 2. I've tried a few search, if, match and vlookup formulas with no luck.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
=INDEX('Sheet 2'B:B, MATCH('Sheet1'A2, 'Sheet2'A:A, 0))
```

You may have to add the quotes back in, I don't know why they disappear when you copy/paste.